# Retrieve JSON data from a hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I store JSON data in HTML hidden fields on the server side. Then I'd like to retrieve that data using Javascript and JQuery on the client side. The problem is that I get a JSON string instead of a JSON object.

This is my code on the server side:

```
<form id="data" style="display: none;">
    <input id="channels" type="hidden" tal:attributes="value python: view.context['ChannelManager'].toJSON(view.channels.values())" />
    <input id="mediaGroups" type="hidden" tal:attributes="value python: view.context['MediaGroupManager'].toJSON(view.mediaGroups.values())" />
</form>
```

This is my code on the client side:

```
copy.channelList = new ChannelTest();
copy.channelList.fromJSONObjectAll($("#data input[id=channels]").val())
```

So I get JSON string instead of JSON object from this, $("#data input[id=channels]").val().

How could I get JSON object without converting JSON string in JSON object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "get JSON object without converting the string"?

Comment: I posted what I think you want but yeah that part is confusing.  You are asking how to convert a json string to an object, without converting a json string to an object...

Comment: When I fill the HTML inputs the data is JSON object, not a JSON String. However, when I get that data on the client side, it's JSON string instead of JSON Object. I'd like to avoid to convert that JSON string in JSON object.

Comment: try editing this: input[id$=channels] and let me know!

Answer (score 6):

```
JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

For older browsers that don't have native JSON support, you can simply include [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) and this will become a usable function.

---

Or you can skip this step with some server side scripting.  You can simply write the JSON into a script tag.  It is parsed implicitly by the script tag instead, as raw javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myObj = <%= myJsonString %>;
  console.log('we got this value: '+ myObj.myValue);
</script>
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid JSON.parse(jsonString) because when I store it on the client side, the data is JSON object. What's the problem? Can I store JSON objects in HTML inputs? I can't use that kind of scripting with framework which I'm using

Comment: `<input>` tags can _only_ have string values.  So if you want to store your data as a string, you have to convert it from a string to a javascript object.  Or you can skip putting in an HTML element at all, and write it directly to the script tag as I outlined above.  But you will never get an `<input>` to store an object directly.  Only a string.  Remember that form elements encode themselves for form submission.  So `<input type="text" name="foo" value="bar">` would encode itself like `?foo=bar`.  If that was a Javascript object, how would it encode itself as a complex object?

Comment: @bribon: Your data on the server is a json string, there's no way to transfer it to the client directly as a javascript object. If you follow Squeegy's suggestion (embedding the data as js variables, then the browser will do the parsing for you when the page is first read)